# how to create seo urls for all views using slug rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am creating an application on which i just want to use all my app's routes should access via seo urls using slugs. i have created a slug field in my database table. this my migration file code

```
  class AddSlugToClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :clients, :slug, :string
    end
  end
```

I have added this code to my controller's show method
my controller's code is:

```
def show    
    @client = Client.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

In my app's model i have added this code

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def slug
    ename.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")  
  end
  validates_presence_of :slug
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

now when i create a new client than client is created by the perfect slug. but when i click show link from the listing page to that clients then getting an error in url which looks like

```
clients/%23<Client::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb59828d4>
```

now please help me to create a seo url for show page while clicking from index view. Current view code:

```
<% @client.each do |client| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= client.ename %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_path(@client) %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(@client) %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try this gem https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: do you have any idea to do this without any gem.

Comment: Please post your index page code.

Comment: You must be generating your link incorrectly. Post the code where you generate your link / url.

Comment: <% @client.each do |client| %>
<tr>
 <td><%= client.ename %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_path(@client) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(@client) %></td>
</tr>

Comment: this is my index page code

Comment: you have added slug field to db and your slug method inside client class is returning ename.

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your question to add your view code, rather than adding it as a comment. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems.

In your view code, your `each` block takes a `client` param - but in your url helpers, you're passing through `@client`. So, you need to remove the `@`.

Your code becomes:

```
<% @client.each do |client| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= client.ename %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', client_path(client) %></td> 
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

*(as an aside, since your `@client` variable that you call `each` on contains multiple records, you should rename it `@clients` - plural. Nothing will break if  you don't do this, but it's not good practice)*

You're second issue is that in your model, since you have a `slug` method which generates the slug from the ename, you don't actually need to have a `slug` column in your database. You should remove that column. The `slug` isn't a value stored in the database, it's just dynamically generated by ruby from the `ename`, which is stored in the database.

There is one other potential issue with this approach, which is that if the ename changes, then so does the slug, and that means if there are any external web pages linking in to the old slug, they will no longer work. But that's probably not worth going into here.

Comment: but i tried to remove slug column from the database but it doesnot work. getting error that undefined method "find_by_slug"